# A conservative extension... or not?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Consider $I$, one of sequential forms of propositional calculus.
>
> Let the alphabet $AI$ consist of propositional variables $Q_0, Q_1,\dots;$ logical constant $\mathfrak{F},$ conjunction symbol $\wedge$, sequence symbol $\vdash$, brackets, and a comma.
>
> Let the set $AxI$ of axioms consist of the only scheme $\Phi\vdash\Phi$.
>
> Let the set $RI$ of inference rules consist of five rules:
> $$
> \begin{align}
> 1.\enspace&\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Phi;\Gamma\vdash\Psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Phi\wedge\Psi};\\\\ 
> 2.\enspace&\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Phi\wedge\Psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Phi};\\\\ 
> 3.\enspace&\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Phi\wedge\Psi}{\Gamma\vdash\Psi};\\\\
> 4.\enspace&\frac{\Gamma,\Phi,\Psi,\Gamma_1\vdash X}{\Gamma,\Psi,\Phi,\Gamma_1\vdash X};\\\\
> 5.\enspace&\frac{\Gamma\vdash\Phi}{\Gamma, \Psi\vdash\Phi}.
> \end{align}
> $$
> Prove that classical propositional calculus is a conservative extension of $I$.

I have got a difficulty with the last step: show that $\mathfrak{F}\vdash\Phi$ is provable in $I$ for an arbitrary formula $\Phi$.

There are no instruments for work with logical constant, so this sequent, as it seems to me, cannot be proven.

Do I mistaken?

UPD:

> $\mathfrak{F}\vdash Q_0$ is unprovable in $I$.

Let $D$ be a proof tree of $\mathfrak{F}\vdash Q_0$. Let $\Phi_0\vdash\Phi_0; \dots;\Phi_n\vdash\Phi_n$ be all the initial sequent occurrences in $D$.

Obviously, $\{\Phi_0,\dots,\Phi_n\}\subset\{\mathfrak{F}\}$: the rules $1 - 5$ allow no reduction of the sets of the antecedents. Hence, $\Phi_i=\mathfrak{F}$ for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

Thus, rules $4$ and $5$ are not applied in $D$.

Using $1$ we can only obtain $\mathfrak{F}\vdash\Phi\wedge\Psi$ with the set of product terms $K(\Phi\wedge\Psi)=K(\Phi)\cup K(\Psi)=\{\mathfrak{F}\}\cup\{\mathfrak{F}\}=\{\mathfrak{F}\}$. Using $2$ and $3$ we do not expand the set of product terms.

Consequently, we can prove no sequent $\mathfrak{F}\vdash\Phi$ for any $\Phi$ such that $K(\Phi)\ne\{\mathfrak{F}\}$, and so, $\mathfrak{F}\vdash Q_0$ is unprovable in $I$.

Comment: IMO your concern is right... The rules above seem to be part of [Minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic) and the Principle of Explosion is not valid in ML.